# template parts wordpress está fora da <section>, como exibir dentro?

Tags: php, wordpress

```
$teste_tp_slugs = ['company', 'search', 'customers'];

foreach ($teste_tp_slugs as $teste_tp_slug) {
    $output = '';
    $output .= '<section id="teste-site-home-' . $teste_tp_slug . '">';
    $output .= '<div class="container">';
    $output .= '<div class="row">';
    $output .= get_template_part('template-parts/home/sections/content', 'company');
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '</div>';
    $output .= '</section>';

    return $output;
}
```

Está exibindo assim, fora da ROW

[image: Está exibindo assim]

O correto seria assim

[image]

Comment: Isso é erro de uso, você está usando uma sintaxe que não corresponde à [orientação do manual](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_part/). Essa função não retorna o valor para concatenar, ela joga a parte na saída. O que acontece aí é que você está gerando a parte imediatamente no HTML, e depois imprime o output (depois de já ter jogado a parte na saída) então é de se esperar que o resultado da função venha em primeiro. Mostre o output até abrir a dív, aí em seguida você chama a função, e depois fecha a div e o resto, aí fica na sequencia desejada.

Comment: @JohnnySilva note que isso é uma característica da função do wordpress que vc está usando. Ele não retorna o valor na função, ele joga direto na saída, por isso não dá pra concatenar. Deu pra entender o que vc quer, mas a função não foi feita pra usar assim (eu até acho que seria melhor que ela funcionasse como vc imaginou, mas quem fez o WP nao pensa da mesma forma). Daria pra fazer uma gambiarra com output buffer, mas acho que fica pior ainda. (começa com `ob_start();`, dá os echo e no final faz `$output  = ob_get_contents()`;

Comment: @Bacco compreendo, realmente tem que ser usando "echo". eu agradeço, ainda estou aprendendo, e careço um pouco das inforações, mas de alguma forma encontrei a informação.

Comment: @JohnnySilva mexi na resposta abaixo do colega Heathcliff para esclarecer melhor, teste e veja se resolveu. O "output buffer" evita saída direta no HTML, e ao final ele joga no return o valor.

Comment: @Bacco muito Obrigado!

Comment: @JohnnySilva note que se vc der um return dentro do foreach só vai vir o primeiro slug, precisa fazer o return fora, acertei isso no código do colega tb

Comment: @Bacco se usar o "echo" nem precisa do ob_start() e o return no final, ele ja exibe todos correntamente rsrs.

Comment: Sim, fica mais simples, por isso sugeri inicialmente o echo. A solução do output buffer só é interessante se depois você precisar concatenar o resultado com alguma outra coisa. Em geral, quanto menos complicar, melhor. Eu sinceramente evito usar output buffer sempre que possível Os raros casos que faz algum sentido usar são justamente esses, de usar algo pronto de terceiros que não funciona como esperado (quase sempre compensa fazer certo e dispensar o código de terceiros, em especial wordpress, que "refaz" algo que o PHP ja tem nativo muito mais simples)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$teste_tp_slugs = ['company', 'search', 'customers'];

ob_start();
foreach ($teste_tp_slugs as $teste_tp_slug) {
    echo '<section id="teste-site-home-' . $teste_tp_slug . '">';
    echo '<div class="container">';
    echo '<div class="row">';
    get_template_part('template-parts/home/sections/content', $teste_tp_slugs);
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</div>';
    echo '</section>';
}
return ob_get_clean();
```

Tenta isso ai :)

Comment: ele retornou apenas o template parts, mas os outros outputs ( <section> etc) não retornou :(

Comment: Tomei a liberdade de mexer no seu post. Considerando que está usando output buffer, precisa do echo e não da concatenação senão não fica em ordem. Aprooveitei e tirei o return do loop para que o loop chegue ao final. Vide comentários na pergunta